# spring security - How to autowire a custom rootObject for WebSecurityExpressionHandler or its subclass?

Tags: java, spring-security

For handling custom expressions in `<intercept-url>`, I provided a custom expression handler to `WebExpressionVoter`. This custom expression handler implements `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` in the same way as `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` and overrides its `createEvaluationContext` method to return a context which has my custom root object set. This custom root object simply extends `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` with another method. This is how DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler does it :

```
public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {
        StandardEvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        SecurityExpressionRoot root = new WebSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);
        root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        ctx.setRootObject(root);

        return ctx;
    }
```

It creates a new object of `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` and assigns it as the root object of the evaluation context it returns, but that forbids `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` from using DI (as its creation is not being handled by Spring). I want to configure my custom expression root **in the xml file**, so that I can inject it in my extension of `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` and use annotations to inject resources into it.

The problem is that the parameters to `WebSecurityExpressionRoot`'s constructors are dynamic, and I can't specify them when specifying it as a bean in xml. Is there a way to inject my custom expression root into my subclass of `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` via DI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` as a `prototype`-scoped bean and instantiate it with the given constructor arguments dynamically:

```
<bean id = "webSecurityExpressionRoot" class = "...WebSecurityExpressionRoot"
    scope = "prototype">
    ...
</bean>
```

.

```
SecurityExpressionRoot root = applicationContext.getBean(
    "webSecurityExpressionRoot", authentication, fi);
```

`ApplicationContext` can be injected into your `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` using `ApplicationContextAware`.

Comment: Thanks. But can we inject the expression root through annotations on a property of type ExpressionRoot ? It would be cleaner.

Comment: @Daud: You'll need to supply constructor arguments somehow anyway. If you don't want to couple `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` with `ApplicationContext`, inject a factory into it.

Comment: Its a little off-topic, but why is coupling our classes with ApplicationContext not considered a good practice ?